# Control what variables appear in $_POST

Tags: php, html

I have a form with several  elements. When they submit the form, I want to use $_POST to see what values have been selected. Now, is it possible to make it so that they only actually get "posted" if a selection is made that is not 0 since since 0 is the default value and if it is 0 they are not actually selecting anything? Or do I have to go through the entire $_POST array to see which ones are non zero?

I don't know which elements I want to access in the $_POST array before hand. I only want my form submission page (the page that goes in the action="" part) to be aware of fields that have non zero selections. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible, however you should be able to just remove the default value before/when the form is submitted, so that default values that have not been changed won't be submitted. I'm not too sure how this can be done though. Maybe try searching for: "change default form values before submitting" OR when you receive these variables, using PHP you can simply ignore the default values and not do anything with them. Could you provide some code, it may help us help you alot more. :)

Comment: It's better/easier/smarter to just ignore them on the PHP side, rather than try to filter them on the Client side.

Answer (score 5):

No. `$_POST` is populated when the environment is set up before your script execution begins, so you don't control its initial contents. It will contain all of the form data.

If you don't know what elements will be there, just loop over all of them. You can also easily remove the ones that are 0 from the array in your code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 0) {
        unset($_POST[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add on some javascript (jquery) to remove all null inputs from your form before they are submitted to your php script

Comment: how would I intercept that before they are submitted to my php form?

Comment: Badly, since JavaScript might not run. You can't trust that the data coming from the browser is going to be in the format you want it to be in period.

Comment: By binding the `submit` event of the form. It will, of course, fail if the user has JavaScript disabled or blocks your script, which means you still need to write your PHP code to handle the entire form. You won't save yourself any coding by modifying the form with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be depending on client-side form filtering, which is utterly unreliable. Other than wasting a few bytes of bandwidth per field, what's the problem with "zeroed" fields getting sent to the server?